# Large Scale Enterprise API Design

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, architecture

I need suggestion on how best we can implement APIs for large scale enterprise application has a couple of child web applications running inside root application. For example Root, Child1 and Child2

There are separate MVP projects for each application is hosted in IIS. MVC apps have only front-end logic, business & data access layer is hosted in another WCF projects(a separate WCF project for every child). Front-end MVC app only routes requests to target WCF application.

Now I'm planning to design APIs for each application. I'm not able to decide whether I should create a separate application which will hold APIs for all the child and root application or should add API in each application. Like front-end MVC projects, APIs will also redirect to centralized WCF application.

There is a common logic applicable to all the APIs(rate limiting,  authentication etc...), if API is in each application then I would have to replication logic in all the three apps.

Comment: Do the APIs rate limit across all of them, or individually? Do you need to deploy the APIs individually? Any scaling differences?

Comment: @tomliversidge Yes, rate limit and other properties of API are applicable to all APIs. There is not need to deploy APIs individually, I can combine all of them into a single application.

Comment: How do you plan on rate limiting across the APIs if they are separate?

Comment: If you combine them all into a single application haven't you answered your own question?

Comment: @tomliversidge Thanks, I would want to keep rate limit same for all APIs for now. In future, it may be different for different APIs.

I want to to know what is the best practice, keeping all APIs into a single application or add APIs in the related application.

Comment: Best practice is to make the best decision for your particular application based on the trade-offs involved with either approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are trade-offs either way.

The advantages of developing separate APIs include;

1. Isolation
2. Easier to change
3. Independently deployable I.e. Can scale independently
4. Might be easier if different development teams are involved in the different APIs

The disadvantages include:

1. Need to decide if you want to repeat common code in each API or extract a common shared module (this then reduces the isolation advantage)
2. More infrastructure / ops to deal with
3. If you want coordination in terms of rate limiting across all APIs this is harder than if they are a single API

My default position would be to develop separate APIs, but your particular use case (routing requests to other things) might be solved by some existing tool such a nginx - I'm not knowledgable about these so cannot advise

Comment: Thanks, I've planned to go with separate application which will hold all the apis.